# Separate custom matchers: one for DTO, one for domain model

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have 2 custom matchers (extending AssertJ's `AbstractAssert`) for a model, and for its DTO object. I wonder if there's a better way to do that.

There's a domain model class `Example`:

```
public class Example {

    private Long id;
    private String value;
}
```

And there's its DTO class that is returned as a response in REST requests:

```
public class ExampleDTO {

    private String value;
}
```

I've created custom matchers for these classes to facilitate testing. But I have trouble with code duplication. Here's a custom matcher for `Example` class:

```
public class ExampleAssert extends AbstractAssert<ExampleAssert, Example> {
    
    // some boilerplate code

    public ExampleAssert hasValue(String expected) {
        Assertions.assertThat(actual.getValue).isEqualTo(expected);
        return this;
    }
}
```

You will notice that the custom matcher class for the DTO is pretty much the duplication of the above.

```
public class ExampleDTOAssert extends AbstractAssert<ExampleDTOAssert, ExampleDTO> {
    
    // some boilerplate code

    public ExampleDTOAssert hasValue(String expected) {
        Assertions.assertThat(actual.getValue).isEqualTo(expected);
        return this;
    }
}
```

I could really use your help to simplify it. Two things that come into my mind:

- inheritence (feels like a code smell though)
- converting one model to the other and use one of the matchers (still a code smell!)

Comment: Other than testing the mapping from one type to the other, how else would the custom matcher be used?  At a glance, it doesn't appear the custom matcher is needed.  In the mapping test, have a **separate** test for each mapped field.

Comment: @AndrewS In the integration tests, I test the REST API endpoints which always return a DTO. In the unit tests I test mainly the service layer that converts the domain model returned by the command pattern operations (commands return domain models) into DTOs. I suppose that extensive and precise unit testing of the command pattern (it's responsible for business logic) and testing just the conversion in the service layer would be okay for the unit tests? What about integration tests when I get a `ResponseEntity<ExampleDTO>` as a response? Do I convert that to domain model and use the matcher?